# Getting Error while deploying the application on iphone

Tags: ios, ios4, ios5

I want to debug my database application after installing on device. The application is running fine over simulator but when deploying it over device I am getting error as:

**Error launching remote program: failed to get the task for process 287**

So I m not able to debug my application.

Please help to resolve this issue.

Answer (score 0):

In the past errors like this were usually due to configuration issues.
In particolar to `code signing entitlements plist file`.

Try to check your project configuration and look for `code signing entitlements plist file`.
If such a file is present check the `get-task-allow` box in there.

Comment: my app doesnt contain entitlements plist file, now what should i do.